# ngx-bootstrap typeahead http request returns object Object

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a typeahead off a service that returns JSON however my code is returning [object Object] instead of the values. What am I doing wrong? It seems like something to do with my typeaheadoption not correctly mapping to result however I'm not sure why this would happen. This comes from the HTTP Async example from ngx-bootstrap: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead

Here's my code for the component and HTML:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { noop, Observable, Observer, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Matches {
  
 bestMatches: Symbols[];
}

interface Symbols {
  "1. symbol": string;
  "2. name":  number;
  "3. type": string;
  "4. region": string;
  "5. marketOpen": Date;
  "6. marketClose": Date;
  "7. timezone": string;
  "8. currency": string;
  "9. matchScore": number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'typeahead-http',
  templateUrl: './typeahead.component.html'
})
export class TypeaheadComponent {
  search: string;
  suggestions$: Observable<Symbols[]>;
  errorMessage: string;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.search = "";
    this.suggestions$ = new Observable
    this.errorMessage = "";

  }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.suggestions$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      observer.next(this.search);
    }).pipe(
      switchMap((query: string) => {
        if (query) {
          return this.http.get<Matches>(
            'https://www.alphavantage.co/query', {
            params: {function:"SYMBOL_SEARCH", keywords: query,apikey:"demo"  }
          }).pipe(
            map((data: Matches) => data.bestMatches|| []),
            tap(() => noop, err => {
              // in case of http error
              this.errorMessage = err && err.message || 'Something goes wrong';
            })
          );
        }
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
}



<pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{ search | json }}</pre>
 
<input [(ngModel)]="search"
        typeaheadOptionField="region"
       [typeahead]="suggestions$"
       [typeaheadAsync]="true"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="Enter GitHub username">
 
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="errorMessage">
  {{ errorMessage }}
</div>

{
    "bestMatches": [
        {
            "1. symbol": "TESO",
            "2. name": "Tesco Corporation USA",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United States",
            "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
            "6. marketClose": "16:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
            "8. currency": "USD",
            "9. matchScore": "0.8889"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TSCO.LON",
            "2. name": "Tesco PLC",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United Kingdom",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "16:30",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+00",
            "8. currency": "GBP",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7273"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TSCDF",
            "2. name": "Tesco plc",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United States",
            "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
            "6. marketClose": "16:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
            "8. currency": "USD",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7143"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TSCDY",
            "2. name": "Tesco plc",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United States",
            "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
            "6. marketClose": "16:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
            "8. currency": "USD",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7143"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TCO.DEX",
            "2. name": "Tesco PLC",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "XETRA",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "20:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+01",
            "8. currency": "EUR",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7143"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TCO.FRK",
            "2. name": "Tesco PLC",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "Frankfurt",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "20:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+01",
            "8. currency": "EUR",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7143"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you paste the  data.bestMatches json you recieve from the api?

Comment: I've added the JSON that would normally be received by the api. It returns the same number of objectst that are listed so I know that it's communicating properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the typehead doesn't know how to retrieve the value from the field name `4. region` since it is invalid according to its internal implementation!
A proper solution is to declare your interface like follow:

```
export interface Symbols {
  symbol: string;
  name:  string;
  type: string;
  region: string;
  marketOpen: string;
  marketClose: string;
  timezone: string;
  currency: string;
  matchScore: string; 
}
```

Next, you need to map the response you receive from the api to your new interface like the following:

```
    // ...
 map((data: any) => (data.bestMatches|| []).map(e=><Symbols>{
            symbol: e["1. symbol"],
            name:  e["2. name"],
            type: e["3. type"],
            region: e["4. region"],
            marketOpen: e["5. marketOpen"],
            marketClose: e["6. marketClose"],
            timezone: e["7. timezone"],
            currency: e["8. currency"],
            matchScore: e["9. matchScore"],
        }))
      // ....
```

Finally, use `region` as a `typeaheadOptionField`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="search"
        typeaheadOptionField="region"
       [typeahead]="suggestions$"
       [typeaheadAsync]="true"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="Enter GitHub username">
```

**[Here is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6mzxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: I've made the modification to this as you mentioned however it still seems to be returning only the objects. There must be some other issue with how it's interpreting the data. Here's the URL to the API call if that helps: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=tesco&apikey=demo