# ngx-bootstrap typeahead displays [object Object] when using itemTemplate and observables

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Is there a solution or a workaround to this?

When one of the options is selected from the typeahead, it appears as "[object Object]". This seems to be a bug with the library when using complex objects with Observables. See [this open GitHub issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/749). This example is a combination of the "Async data" and the "Item template" example from [the docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/typeahead?tab=overview).

[image]

```js
// app.component.html
<pre class="card card-block card-header mb-3">Model: {{ asyncSelected  | json}}</pre>
<input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
       [typeahead]="dataSource"
       [typeaheadAsync]="true"
       [typeaheadItemTemplate]="customItemTemplate"
       class="form-control">

<ng-template #customItemTemplate let-model="item" let-index="index">
  <h5>This is: {{model | json}} Index: {{ index }}</h5>
</ng-template>
```

```js
// app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  asyncSelected?: string;
  dataSource: Observable<any[]>;
  statesComplex: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alabama', region: 'South' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Alaska', region: 'West' }
  ];
 
  constructor() {
    this.dataSource = new Observable((observer: Subscriber<string>) => {
      // Runs on every search
      observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
    })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((token: string) => this.getStatesAsObservable(token))
      );
  }
 
  getStatesAsObservable(token: string): Observable<any[]> {
    const query = new RegExp(token, 'i');
 
    return of(
      this.statesComplex.filter((state: any) => {
        return query.test(state.name);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular 15 and ngx-bootstrap 10.2.0. The `FormsModule` and `TypeaheadModule.forRoot()` are imported in the module file.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639030/ngx-bootstrap-typeahead-http-request-returns-object-object) may be related.

Answer (score 0):

When using `typeaheadItemTemplate` with complex data (objects rather than strings in the datasource) you are also required to define the `typeaheadOptionsField` so that the component doesn't try (and fail) to render the whole object in the search field.

```js
// app.component.html
...
<input ...
       [typeaheadItemTemplate]="customItemTemplate"
       typeaheadOptionsField="name">

...
```

`name` here is the name of the property on the object, which can be nested or be a function.